# Program is not running properly

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that is supposed to construct a 52 card pile, then deal the cards out to n number of players (it is possible for some players to have an extra card). The winner is the one with the Ace of Spades card.

```
public class CardGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    int numberOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    CardPile deck = CardPile.makeFullDeck(); 
    CardPile [] players = new CardPile[numberOfPlayers];

    for (int i=0;i<numberOfPlayers;i++) {  
      int numofnum = i%numberOfPlayers;

      players[i] = new CardPile();
    }

    for (int i=0;i<52;i++) { 
      int numofnum =i%numberOfPlayers;

      CardPile curPlayer = players[i%numberOfPlayers];
      Card nextCard = deck.get(i);
      players[numofnum].addToBottom(nextCard); 

    }

    for (int i=0;i<numberOfPlayers;i++) {  

      if (players[i].find(Suit.SPADES, Value.ACE) != -1) {

        System.out.println("Player " + i + " is the winner");
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Here is CardPile

```
public class CardPile{
  private Card[] cards; 
  private int numCards;


  public static void main(String[] args){


  }


  public CardPile(){
    Card[] constructor = new Card[52]; 
    cards = constructor; 
    numCards = 0;  
  }

  public boolean isEmpty(){
    return this.numCards==0; 
  }

  public void addToBottom(Card c){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<52;i++){  
      if(cards[i]==null){
        break;
      }
    }
    numCards = i; 
    cards[i] = c; 
  }


  public Card get(int i){
    return cards[i]; 
  }

  public Card remove(int i){
    Card removed = cards[i];
    for(i = i;i<51;i++){
      cards[i]=cards[i+1];  
    }
    cards[51]= null; 
    numCards=numCards-1;
    return removed;
  }

  public int find(Suit a,Value b){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<52;i++){
      if(cards[i].getSuit()==a && cards[i].getValue()==b){  
        break;
      }
      else{
        i = -1; 
        return i;
      }
    }
    return i;
  }

  public  String toString(){
    String x = "";  
    String y = "";

    for(int i=0;i<numCards;i++){  
      y = cards[i].toString();
      x = x + i + "." + y +" "; 
    }
    return x;

  }

  public static CardPile makeFullDeck(){

    CardPile pile = new CardPile();  
    for(Value v: Value.values()){
      for(Suit s: Suit.values()){
        pile.addToBottom(new Card(s,v)); 
      }
    }

    UtilityCode.shuffle(pile.cards, pile.numCards);  

    return pile;

  }


}
```

My problem is that sometimes when I run CardGame it prints out "player x is the winner" but sometimes it does not print anything. Can anyone help me please ? Thank you

Comment: Please do debugging to find out what is the issue. To find out why sometimes it prints the winner and sometimes not, put print statements to monitor values of variables, output of conditions, calculations, etc, to find out what goes wrong and where?

Answer (score 1):

`CardPile.find()` will return -1 unless the first card is the one being searched for.  Change it to this:

```
public int find(Suit a,Value b){
    for(int i=0;i<52;i++){
      if(cards[i].getSuit()==a && cards[i].getValue()==b){  
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```